# debuginfo-install SyntaxError:invalid syntax

Tags: python, linux, gdb

I want to use `debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-157.e17_3.1.x86_64` to use debugging function of gdb.

But when I run this command, the terminal shows this error.

```
File "/usr/bin/debuginfo-install", line 58
    except yum.Errors.YumBaseError, e:
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I use `yum remove yum-utils` to remove `debuginfo-install` and try to reinstall it.But it doesn't work.I don't konw how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.The reason is simple, because my python version is error and `debuginfo-install` is running with python 2.7.So I modify this python script, not running with python 3.5.